# Конструктор на сайте

Tags: site

Здравствуйте как называется технология или скрипт который используется на сайте [vsemaiki.ru](http://kz.vsemayki.ru/constructor/?producttype=case_iphone_5_flat) там есть конструктор для футболок

или [тут](http://vsemayki.kz/constructor)

Comment: Не открывается у меня...

Comment: Там просто куча ошибок в коде. А по сути - там используется обычный [Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) и рисуют все, что нужно.

Comment: Там, похоже, самопал. Кто-то потратил много времени :) Там все, что можно: canvas, bootstrap, html5, ajax/json... много-много-много-много кода :)